# mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar library does not work in the .jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar, netbeans-10

I have created a java application that connects to a mysql database. I imported the libraries as a request from the ide netbenas 10 and trying it works. But when I export the application in jar format, when I go to run it the connection to the DB no longer works.
Does anyone know how I can do?

Comment: Either create an uber jar by extracting the dependencies with your project classes or reference the external library using the manifest file.

Comment: *when I go to run it the connection to the DB no longer works* this is no error description. Add a detaild error message

Answer (score 0):

Please add the mysql jdbc jar in the classpath while executing your Jar.